# Multiple split and assign order_id

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have some address string that needs to be analyzed for each component.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58b2c/2)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ("ID" int, "address" varchar(41));

INSERT INTO Table1 ("ID", "address")
VALUES
    (1, 'calle 15, lomas del avila'),
    (2, 'calle av. solano edif:Apalache apt-15');
```

So I need to split by different characters like ( `.`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `<space>`, `-`)

For one character I know how to do it.

```
SELECT ID, s.token
FROM   Table1 t, unnest(string_to_array(t.address, ' ')) s(token);
```

**How chain multiple unnest and how I assign an OrderID?**

```
| ID |         token | orderID
|----|---------------|--------
|  1 |         calle |    1
|  1 |           15, |    2
|  1 |         lomas |    3
|  1 |           del |    4
|  1 |         avila |    5
|  2 |         calle |    1
|  2 |           av. |    2
|  2 |        solano |    3
|  2 | edif:Apalache |    4
|  2 |        apt-15 |    5
```

For this example second row `15,` will be split into `15` and `null` so second result can be discard and order won't change.

But in the last 2 rows `edif:Apalache` and `apt-15` the second split will produce `edif`, `Apalache`, `apt` and `15` so orderID will go from 4 to 7:

```
|  2 | edif     |    4
|  2 | Apalache |    5
|  2 | apt      |    6
|  2 | 15       |    7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [translate()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT "ID", token, row_number() over (partition by "ID")
FROM (
    SELECT "ID", s.token
    FROM   
        Table1 t, 
        unnest(string_to_array(translate(t.address, '.,:;-', '     '), ' ')) 
            s(token)
    WHERE token <> ''
    ) sub
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58b2c/17).